# Waiting and Scheduling time of thread In android

Tags: android, multithreading, timer

I want to do like,

I have **1** task that I want repeat for every **30 sec**. Means the **waiting time** for that task is **30 sec** and **scheduling time** is also **30 sec.** Then I have other stuffs that I want to work in waiting time. **Lets eg.** I have dice, that rotate for 30 sec and wait for 30 sec. Now in between waiting time I want to show count-down timer for 30 sec. Like 30 29 28...so on(Stop timer for dice). When its 0 then again dice rotates for 30 sec.

I know there is class like **Timer , CoutDownTimer**. But exactly which class is suitable for my scenario is hard to find me.

Please help me. Thanks is advance

Comment: have look [this](http://tekeye.uk/android/examples/android-dice-code) hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `TimerTask`.

```
write a class which extends TimerTask



public class PeriodictaskClass extends TimerTask{   
        public void run() {
            // write code snippet here
        }
    }
```

You can execute this by calling

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new PeriodictaskClass(), 0, 30000);
```